# Magento 2.3.1 styles.css not loaded on frontend

Tags: magento2.3.1, sample-data, styles

I just installed a fresh Magento 2.3.1, and I ran the following code to deploy sampledata. `bin/magento sampledata:deploy`

The sample data are successfully installed but `styles.css` is not loading. I have checked `pub/media` folder, and I can see the `styles.css` does exist.

I tried the following step to fix the problem

1. `bin/magento setup:upgrade` , `bin/magento setup:di:compile` and `bin/magento cache:flush`
2. I cleared all content from folder **generated, var/cache, var/page_cache, var/view_preprocessed, pub/static/** and *flushed cache* again.
3. I give pub folder 777 permission.

but the `styles.css` is still not loaded on the frontpage.

This is the first time I experienced this weird issue. any suggestions?

I'm using **luma** theme and **Magento 2.3.1**

[image]

PS:

> styles-m.css and styles-l.css are loaded successfully. it's only the
>   pub/media/styles.css not loaded.

Comment: Can you please check for any console logs in the browser? Any error logs

Comment: Just checked console tlog. no errors, but there's a warning saying "jquery-migrate.js:45 JQMIGRATE: jQuery.attrFn is deprecated". This should be the problem?

Comment: Is it default Magento or you have made changes like installing third-party extensions or your own?

Comment: @RajMohanR I did install some third-party extensions.

Comment: In the browser side for the CSS URL's what response did it display either 404 or some thing else?

Comment: @RajMohanR no 404 error. I can successfully open the styles.css with URL in browser.

Comment: Can you please mention in which Magento mode you are? Does your site looks broken?

Comment: @RajMohanR It's running on Developer mode. Yes my site looks broken on frontpage. I have just uploaded a screenshot in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95904/discussion-between-raj-mohan-r-and-magento-learner).

Comment: Can you check pub/static/.htaccess file missing or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can change this setting by login to your Magento

> admin panel -> then go to
>   Stores>Configuration>Advanced>Developer>Sign Static Files
>   (dev_static_sign) -> No.

(or)

You can also disable this from database by running below query :

```
insert into core_config_data (config_id, scope, scope_id, path, value) values (null, 'default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', 0);
```

and also check

> 1) Open app/etc/di.xml
>
> 2) Replace all
>   Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink
>   occurrences with
>   Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy

Thanks

Comment: I have tried all metod you mentioned, and cleared both Magento and browser cache. the styles.css is still not loaded on the frontend. really weird issue.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if you are still waiting for an answer on this, but in case it helps others: The Luma demo site loads the `pub/media/styles.css` through the backend.  So in the backend:

1. go to **Content->Design->Configuration**
2. click the **Action->Edit button** for the site you are working on,
3. Expand the HTML Head section,
4. Add this text to Scripts and Stylesheets:

.

```
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="{{MEDIA_URL}} styles.css" />
```

Then clear the cache and reload.  (You can check this in the Luma backend first -- that is what I based this on.)

This strikes me as odd for the demo -- it's not documented as far as I can tell and it doesn't fit with any of the magento online docs describing how to make style changes.  On top of that, this styles.css file is compacted and hard to read, and I could not find the source for it.

I wanted a version of it that I could make some sense out of, so I used sed to add new lines and semicolons.  I had to hand edit it a bit because my sed scripts didn't handle two "}} characters in a row properly.

I am putting [this file here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ce3ni5s68e701t/styles.less?dl=0) in case it helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I found this problem in this moment and change the .htaccess into the folder /pub it works now!! :D

Answer (score 0):

first you need remove temp folder :

```
rm -rf var/di/ var/generation/ var/composer_home var/cache/ var/tmp/ var/page_cache/ var/session/ var/view_preprocessed/ pub/static/frontend
```

Add Code in mysql :

```
insert into core_config_data (config_id, scope, scope_id, path, value) values (null, 'default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', 0);
```

[image]

click go
run all commands :

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade 
php bin/magento setup:di:compile 
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

change folder permission :

```
sudo chmod -R 0777 ../folder-Name
```

thanks